# Local wsfed endpoint used with hrd in ThinkTecture IdentityServer

Tags: identity, claims-based-identity, ws-federation, thinktecture-ident-server, home-directory

I'm trying to get my head around setting Home Realm Discovery in ThinkTecture IdentityServer. I have two external identity providers but would also like to have a link to the local wsfed endpoint from the same screen. I've seen Brock's response on [GitHub](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2/issues/484) referring to this problem, but cannot get my head around the concept. I've registered IdSrv wsfed endpoint as an identity provider, but how can I configure the IdSrv hrd as a RP? At the moment I'm getting server error: invalid realm. The realm is actually equal to Site ID from General Configuration?

Comment: A link to Brock's answer to this question on IdSrv project page on GitHub -> https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2/issues/484